# How to extract data from dose.p [R package MASS] atomic vector result

Tags: r

I used dose.p to calculate EDx (e.g. ED50) data from a glm model (probit model).

```
glm.logit <- glm(cbind(nok,nges-nok) ~ log(dosis), family=binomial(lk), data=edx.data)
r <- dose.p(glm.logit,p=seq(0.1,0.9,0.2))
```

r is as follows:

```
             Dose         SE
p = 0.1: 0.866650 0.10578072
p = 0.3: 1.301613 0.06405342
p = 0.5: 1.574622 0.05168480
p = 0.7: 1.847632 0.05971840
p = 0.9: 2.282595 0.09898567
```

exp(r) would give the right EDx:

```
> exp(r)
             Dose         SE
p = 0.1: 2.378928 0.10578072
p = 0.3: 3.675219 0.06405342
p = 0.5: 4.828918 0.05168480
p = 0.7: 6.344778 0.05971840
p = 0.9: 9.802082 0.09898567
```

But how to extract all numbers (doses and SE) to be able to calculate not only the EDx but also lower and upper confidence limits? At the end I would like to calculate such a table:

```
  p          Dose        Lower limit       Upper limit
0.1    exp(2.379)   exp(2.379-0.106)  exp(2.379+0.106)
0.2 ...
```

I tried to extract these data but got an error message:

```
> se <- r$SE
    Error in r$SE : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
```

Thank you very much in advance

Christian

Comment: Welcome to the site. This looks like it is solely about `R`. If so, I will migrate it to the StackOverflow site. If not, please edit it to show what statistical questions you have. Thanks!

Comment: To extract the standard errors, use `se <- attr(r,"SE")`. To access single SEs, you could use `attr(r,"SE")[1]` and so on. To see what attributes `r` has, type `attributes(r)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can extract using 'attributes'. To place into a data.frame use

```
df = data.frame(p = seq(0.1,0.9,0.2), Dose.exp = unname(r[1:5]), SE = unname(attributes(r)$SE[, 1]))
```